# Why does sed make line terminators visible in vim

Tags: regex, vim, sed, newline

I have `textfile` with CRLF line terminators. The file contains two lines of text (displayed in Vim) :

```
foo
bar
```

Say I want to find pattern `foo` and replace the entire line with `goo`, so I run:

```
sed -i 's/foo.*/goo/' textfile
```

After the operation `textfile` shows in Vim like this:

```
goo
bar^M
```

My question is: Why has the previously hidden carriage return become visible in Vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command:

```
sed -i 's/foo.*/goo/' textfile
```

removed the `\r` from the end of the line since `\r` is just an arbitrary char for sed on UNIX, matched by `.*`.

Looks like Vim is smart enough to not display the ^M for Windows style carriage returns as long as they are used *consistently* in the file. Because of the above sed command they are not used consistently any more as it only removes the `\r` from lines matching `foo.*`.

If that is a problem for you I recommend to use:

```
sed -i 's/foo.*/goo\r/' textfile
```

---

[sydill's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133833/why-does-sed-make-line-terminators-visible-in-vim/42134282?noredirect=1#comment71436436_42134282) pointed me to the right manual section which describes this behaviour: `:help file-formats`:

> ... If you start editing a new file and the 'fileformats' option is not empty
>   (which is the default), Vim will try to detect whether the lines in the file
>   are separated by the specified formats.  When set to "unix,dos", Vim will
>   check for lines with a single  (as used on Unix and Amiga) or by a 
>    pair (MS-DOS).  Only when **ALL** lines end in , 'fileformat' is set
>   to "dos", otherwise it is set to "unix".  When 'fileformats' includes "mac",
>   and no  characters are found in the file, 'fileformat' is set to "mac". ...

Comment: This answers my question and offers a solution to the issue. Thank you!

Comment: This is precisely what's happening, but maybe could be worded _consistently_ instead of _consequently_? There is a useful paragraph in `:h file-formats` that I'd add to this answer as well (If you start editing...Only when ALL lines end in <CR><NL>, 'fileformat' is set to "dos", otherwise it is set to "unix")

Comment: Let me change/add that. Thanks for the comment!